# How to edit the height input-group-addons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a text field with a glyphicon icon on hover to show a tooltip. I added a label outside of that text field. After that I could not fix the height of input group addon with the size of textfield

```js
$("a.my-tool-tip").tooltip();
```

```css
a.my-tool-tip,
a.my-tool-tip:hover,
a.my-tool-tip:visited {
  color: black;
}

.input-group {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-group">
  <label for="my-label">My Label</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="security" id="security">
  <p class="unit">You msg here</p>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
            <a class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip here">
                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></i>
            </a>
        </span>
  </input>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dirty solution!

```js
$("a.my-tool-tip").tooltip();
```

```css
a.my-tool-tip,
a.my-tool-tip:hover,
a.my-tool-tip:visited {
  color: black;
}

.input-group {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

label[for="my-label"] {
position: absolute;
top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-group">
  <label for="my-label">My Label</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="security" id="security">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
            <a class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip here">
                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></i>
            </a>
        </span>
  </input>
</div>
```

Make lable `absolute`

Comment: thank you for the dirty solution :) I have a slight change in my requirement. I have a p tag after the input. How can I fix that.

Comment: Your Welcome :) i think you should make `absolute` `p` tag too.